# Count rows that match criteria in the parent table, and have at least one qualifying record in a child table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables:

**Consents**

| ConsentID | Consent Date | Inspection Required |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 Aug 2021 | Yes |
| 2 | 10 Sept 2021 | No |

**Consent Reviews**

| ConsentID | Review Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 Aug 2021 |
| 1 | 15 Aug 2021 |
| 1 | 2 Sept 2021 |
| 2 | 5 Sept 2021 |

I would like to create a DAX measure that counts the **Consents** that have **Inspection Required** = Yes and (**Consent Date** is between the measures [Period Start] and [Period End] or the Consent has a **Consent Review** record in the same period).  Note the use of brackets - I have some criteria that must be matched in the parent table, and other criteria where there is *either* a match in the parent table *or* a match in the child table.

Looking at my example if the period equated to August or September we would get 1 qualifying Consent.  If it was October we would get zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have following two tables

```
|                   Consents                     |
|-----------|--------------|---------------------|
| ConsentID | Consent Date | Inspection Required |
|-----------|--------------|---------------------|
| 1         | 2021-08-01   | Yes                 |
| 2         | 2021-09-10   | No                  |
| 3         | 2021-10-01   | Yes                 |
| 4         | 2021-12-01   | No                  |
| 5         | 2021-04-05   | Yes                 |
| 8         | 2021-08-01   | Yes                 |

|         Consent Reviews       |
|-----------------|-------------|
| ConsentID       | Review Date |
|-----------------|-------------|
| 1               | 2021-08-10  |
| 1               | 2021-08-15  |
| 1               | 2021-09-02  |
| 2               | 2021-09-05  |
| 4               | 2021-08-22  |
| 4               | 2021-08-23  |
| 5               | 2021-04-05  |
| 5               | 2021-08-31  |
```

and you have two Measures as `periodStart` and `periodEnd`

the following measures returns count for a `periodStart=2021-08-01` and `periodEnd=2021-09-30`

```
_count = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Consent Reviews'[ConsentID] ),
    CALCULATETABLE (
        'Consent Reviews',
        CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES ( Consents[ConsentID] ),
            Consents[Inspection Required] = "Yes"
        )
    ),
    FILTER (
        'Consent Reviews',
        'Consent Reviews'[Review Date] >= [periodStart]
            && 'Consent Reviews'[Review Date] <= [periodEnd]
    )
)
    + COUNTROWS (
        EXCEPT (
            SUMMARIZE (
                FILTER (
                    'Consents',
                    Consents[Inspection Required] = "Yes"
                        && ( Consents[Consent Date] >= [periodStart]
                        && Consents[Consent Date] <= [periodEnd] )
                ),
                Consents[ConsentID]
            ),
            SUMMARIZE (
                CALCULATETABLE (
                    'Consent Reviews',
                    CALCULATETABLE (
                        'Consent Reviews',
                        CALCULATETABLE (
                            VALUES ( Consents[ConsentID] ),
                            Consents[Inspection Required] = "Yes"
                        )
                    ),
                    FILTER (
                        'Consent Reviews',
                        'Consent Reviews'[Review Date] >= [periodStart]
                            && 'Consent Reviews'[Review Date] <= [periodEnd]
                    )
                ),
                'Consent Reviews'[ConsentID]
            )
        )
    )
```

[image: Solution]